# SharePoint 2010 PerformancePoint Services scorecard not showing numbers for hierarchies

Tags: sharepoint, performancepoint

I am trying to create a scorecard in SharePoint 2010 PerformancePoint dashboard designer. I had a very similar dashboard in performancePoint 2007 working fine. Basically, I have created a KPI which uses my analysis services cube as the data source. In the scorecard I just use this KPI. Let's say it is Total Sales Actual and Target. The numbers show up fine upto that point. Now what I really want is the drill down by region and stores. So I dran in my dimension hierarchy from the cube and select all regions and the children. However, when I drill down I don't see numbers for any store it is just blank. It just shows numbers for the top level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was causing the issue but I was able to fix the problem by going to a different database for my cube (same cube hosted on a different box). I think my dev SQL box might have had some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging your dimension hierarchy to the right side of the parent box. If you hold it there for a second a blue line shows up on the right side of the box and the tool tip says "last child". If you drag to the other edges it can be a parent, or sibling, which don't seem to drill down to the totals.